# Can I inherit deleted overloads when overriding a member function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here's a minimal example of my issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    virtual void Print(double d) = 0;
    void Print(int a) = delete;
};

struct Bar : public Base
{
    void Print(double d)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << d << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Bar b;
    int a = 1;
    b.Print(a);
}
```

I want `b.Print(a)` to generate a compiler error. I can do it if I add `void Print(int a) = delete;` in `Bar`, but I'd like the `Base` struct to handle this (in my actual use case, I have multiple struct inheriting from `Base`). I can't find how to do this.

Comment: why do you need this? If `Bar` should not have a `Print` method, why did you define one?

Comment: you want to avoid all implicit conversions? Only `int` -> `double` ?

Comment: I had to read twice and then still guess to understand that you are concerned about the implicit conversion. I still do not understand completely what the aim is. Please clarify the quesiton

Comment: Maybe you want an error for defining `void Print(double d)` not only when it is called?

Comment: This is an example for easy reproducibility. The real life example involves class from boost (boost::property_tree::ptree) and custom one. Custom one has a constructor from ptree, and I want to prevent the implicit conversion.

Comment: `Bar b; float a = 1; b.Print(a);` -- This also compiles with no errors.  So is it only `int`, or any type that isn't exactly a `double`?

Comment: anything other than an `int` passed to `Bar::print` should be an error?

Comment: Let's say yes, I only want Print to be called with a double, nothing else.

Comment: Don't pass a naked `double`.  Pass a simple struct, maybe call it `Double`,  that wraps a `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay with `virtual void Print(double d) = 0;` then you cannot prevent the implicit conversion happening in `Bar` by any measure taken in `Base`. When you call `b.Print(1)` then namelookup finds `Bar::Print` and stops. Overload resolution then only considers `Bar::Print`.

I see two options: Either you give up on passing a `double`, or you give up on `void Print(double)` being the virtual method that gets overriden in derived classes.

---

Generally, one way to prevent implicit conversions is to write a function template and rely on argument deduction. For example `void foo(auto x)` will always deduce the "right" type for `x`. Though you cannot make the virtual method a template.

If you can change the signature of `Print` you can place the "avoid conversion template" elsewhere. This is similar to what PaulMcKenzie suggested in a comment:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Double {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,double>>>
    Double(T value)  : value(value) {}
    double value;
};


struct Base
{
    virtual void Print(Double d) = 0;
    void Print(int a) = delete;
};

struct Bar : public Base
{
    void Print(Double d) override
    {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << d.value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Bar b;
    int a = 1;
    double c = 42.0;
    b.Print(c);   // OK
    b.Print(a);   // ERROR
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Er9nsWc8)

---

Only later I realized that there is a way to get an error by deleting the method in `Base`. It is viable if you can give up on the virtual on `void Print(double)` (but instead make a different method virtual):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    void Print(double d) { doPrint(d); }
    void Print(int a) = delete;
private:
    virtual void doPrint(double d) = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Base
{
    private:
    void doPrint(double d) override
    {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << d << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Bar b;
    int a = 1;
    b.Print(4);   // error as desired
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PKW3oqcav)

Rather than overriding `Print` the derived classes override `doPrint` which can be `private`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Bar::Print()` hides the overloads in `Base`.

We need to bring the other overrides into `Bar` which we do using `using`:

```
    using Base::Print;

    void Print(double d) override
    {
        std::cout << "Bar: " << d << std::endl;
    }
```

Now the attempt to use `Print(a);` is ill-formed.

This *cannot* be achieved by changing only the `Base` implementation.